# Ação no botão para centralizar texto

Tags: java, primefaces, java-ee, bootstrap-3

Alguém poderia me auxiliar como eu poderia fazer para que quando quando eu digitar qualquer texto em um input, aí eu tenho um botão em cima do meu input na qual quero centralizar esse texto digitado. Alguém poderia me auxiliar como eu posso fazer?

Aqui é o botão na qual quero que faça a ação (de como centralizar o meu texto):

```
<p:commandLink id="btn_close_users_modal33"
               styleClass="btn btn-default" action="">
    <i class="fa  fa-align-center fa-fw" />
</p:commandLink>
```

E aqui é o meu input quando eu digitar o texto, quero selecionar o que foi digitado e clicar no botão para fazer a ação de centralizar o texto:

```
 <h:inputText value="#{frameBean.editorText1}" autocomplete="off"
              styleClass="form-control" tabindex="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar jQuery para adicionar a classe `text-center` do Bootstrap ao `input`.

Por exemplo:

**O JavaScript e jQuery**

```
<script>
    function centralizar(){
        $(".input-centralizar").addClass("text-center");
    }
<script>
```

Usei `.input-centralizar` que representa o `input` que tem essa classe CSS. Usei classe CSS, neste exemplo, porque pode ser que seu `<h:form>` não esteja com `prependId="false"`, pois quando está `true` (padrão) todos os elementos filhos desse *form* recebem o `id` do *form* automaticamente o torna inviável a obtenção no elemento pelo seu `id`.

**O link de ação**

```
<p:commandLink id="btn_close_users_modal33" onclick="centralizar()"
           styleClass="btn btn-default" action="">
    <i class="fa  fa-align-center fa-fw" />
</p:commandLink>

<h:inputText value="#{frameBean.editorText1}" autocomplete="off"
          styleClass="form-control input-centralizar" tabindex="0"/>
```